# How to group rows of consecutive dates sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql table that contains data as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   Resource    VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
  ,PB          VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,Quantity    NUMERIC(14,2) NOT NULL
  ,Start_Date  VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
  ,Finish_Date VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',16011.172,'2-Jan-2021','2-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',102794.7967,'2-Jan-2021','4-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',1720.878774,'2-Jan-2021','2-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',13558.22633,'2-Jan-2021','2-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',7764.452475,'2-Jan-2021','3-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',36510.98833,'3-Jan-2021','4-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',24459.19598,'4-Jan-2021','4-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',21713.47076,'4-Jan-2021','4-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',13547.40874,'4-Jan-2021','4-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',27231.77234,'4-Jan-2021','5-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',104022.7492,'4-Jan-2021','6-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',6449.903233,'5-Jan-2021','5-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',10220.21966,'5-Jan-2021','5-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',2694.762301,'5-Jan-2021','5-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',126261.2533,'5-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',36918.74602,'6-Jan-2021','7-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',113440.8759,'7-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',2922.42253,'9-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',3350.48394,'9-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',7349.647811,'9-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',42555.83264,'9-Jan-2021','10-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',11175.69388,'9-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',1934.254711,'9-Jan-2021','9-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',53541.27895,'9-Jan-2021','11-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',3367.272434,'10-Jan-2021','10-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',3716.841168,'10-Jan-2021','11-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',404.8054109,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',27308.51547,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',245.6034221,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',415.0741536,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',1018.350498,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',1283.883699,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',241.7214407,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',478.0247084,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',109.835884,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',801.0082568,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',89.39607135,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',9223.286622,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',35624.14072,'12-Jan-2021','12-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',13357.03326,'12-Jan-2021','13-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',6395.991573,'12-Jan-2021','13-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',24785.74254,'13-Jan-2021','13-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',130227.351,'13-Jan-2021','16-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',7434.296526,'13-Jan-2021','13-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',9569.374794,'13-Jan-2021','13-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',38780.92371,'13-Jan-2021','14-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',38739.36462,'14-Jan-2021','15-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',20199.57676,'15-Jan-2021','15-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',12178.18556,'15-Jan-2021','16-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',28707.31901,'16-Jan-2021','16-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',18182.53674,'16-Jan-2021','16-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',34636.32161,'16-Jan-2021','17-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',80749.62428,'16-Jan-2021','18-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',22715.41542,'17-Jan-2021','18-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',19369.6761,'18-Jan-2021','18-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',19138.5662,'18-Jan-2021','18-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',34673.92042,'18-Jan-2021','19-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',107038.3668,'18-Jan-2021','21-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',28150.06205,'19-Jan-2021','20-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',564.1222179,'20-Jan-2021','20-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',1480.405727,'20-Jan-2021','20-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',20916.77668,'20-Jan-2021','21-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',7187.011316,'22-Jan-2021','22-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',13131.63449,'22-Jan-2021','22-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',59399.38963,'22-Jan-2021','23-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',105983.4664,'22-Jan-2021','25-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',38388.89162,'23-Jan-2021','24-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',34649.41728,'24-Jan-2021','24-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',25377.05567,'24-Jan-2021','25-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',769.5619956,'25-Jan-2021','25-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',1066.020068,'25-Jan-2021','25-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#2','pb12',11919.38042,'25-Jan-2021','25-Jan-2021');
INSERT INTO #mytable(Resource,PB,Quantity,Start_Date,Finish_Date) VALUES ('Equip#1','pb12',16511.07877,'25-Jan-2021','25-Jan-2021');
```

I would like to group the Quantity by consecutive Start and Finish dates belonging to the same Resource and PB. that is if StartDate <= Previous FinshDate or StartDate = Previous FinshDate+1, then the records should be grouped. However, if StartDate > Previous FinshDate+1, then it should constitute a new record.
for example

````
    and Start_date2 = 6-Jan-2021 and finish_date1 = 7-Jan-2021```
These two records should group together and output a single row with
 ```Start_date = 2-Jan-2021 and finish_date = 7-Jan-2021```

Similar 
  if Start_date1 = 2-Jan-2021 and finish_date1 = 5-Jan-2021
    and Start_date2 = 4-Jan-2021 and finish_date1 = 7-Jan-2021

However 
     if Start_date1 = 2-Jan-2021 and finish_date1 = 5-Jan-2021
    and Start_date2 = 7-Jan-2021 and finish_date1 = 9-Jan-2021
These two records should group together and output a different rows because the StartDate2 isnt contained in the period of the first row.

I have tried a few examples on SO, but the closes I get is the below code

 ;WITH t AS (
  SELECT  Start_Date d,MAX(Finish_Date) as EndDate ,SUM(Quantity) as qty , PB, Resource,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start_Date,PB,Resource) i 
  FROM #mytable

  GROUP BY Start_Date,PB,Resource--,StartDate
)
SELECT  Resource AS Equipment, PB,SUM(qty) as Quantity,  MIN(d) as Start_Date,MAX(EndDate) as Finish_Date
FROM t
GROUP BY PB,Resource,DATEDIFF(day,i,d) 
order by Equipment;

With the above code, my SQL results in the below result set :

Equipment   PB  Quantity    Start_Date  Finish_Date
Equip#1 pb12    150359.63   6-Jan-2021  9-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    208680.58   4-Jan-2021  9-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    102794.80   2-Jan-2021  4-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    115992.47   23-Jan-2021 25-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    66586.40    22-Jan-2021 23-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    126176.94   18-Jan-2021 21-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    198756.61   14-Jan-2021 18-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    80570.33    13-Jan-2021 14-Jan-2021
Equip#1 pb12    56331.12    12-Jan-2021 13-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    250749.75   4-Jan-2021  9-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    36510.99    3-Jan-2021  4-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    39054.73    2-Jan-2021  3-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    12688.94    25-Jan-2021 25-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    142076.41   20-Jan-2021 25-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    82193.66    18-Jan-2021 20-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    57351.74    16-Jan-2021 18-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    130227.35   13-Jan-2021 16-Jan-2021
Equip#2 pb12    47749.66    10-Jan-2021 13-Jan-2021

instead of 

Equipment   PB  Quantity    Start_Date  Finish_Date
Equip#1 pb12    461835.01   02-Jan-21   09-Jan-21
Equip#1 pb12    644413.87   12-Jan-21   25-Jan-21
Equip#2 pb12    798603.23   02-Jan-21   25-Jan-21

Can anyone assist.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b261/1/0
````

Comment: can you add your code in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4649/1

Comment: Why are your dates stored as strings and not dates?

Comment: @Ajay2707 Here is the Sqlfiddle link.. Had to truncate the data as it was >8000 char 
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/da3fb/1/0

Comment: @Stu -> I'm not sure if that should affect the results, however, the dates are datetime in the table definition.

Comment: @olufikayoolowoyo it will certainly have an impact yes since ordering and aggregations will be based on alphabetic `string` ordering and not date ordering. `select Max(start_date) from #mytable` = '9-jan-2021' but you would expect it to be 25 jan

Comment: @Stu I get you, I have updated the column definition in the SQLFiddle. however, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @olufikayoolowoyo Yes just pointing out it will give you incorrect results; and if your date values don't have a time component, why would your actual columns be `datetime` and not `date`

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, first, need to select the result with Previous_FinshDate in the same row, and based on your condition set flag and group by.

Please find the following 2 queries for the detail list and group by sum for the final result.

```
-- Details query---
select * from (
select *,

case when (convert(date,Start_Date) <=convert(date,Previous_FinshDate) 
        or convert(date,Start_Date) = dateadd(dd,1, convert(date,Previous_FinshDate))) then 1 else 0 end as flag,
case when convert(date,Start_Date) > dateadd(dd,1, convert(date,Previous_FinshDate)) then 1 else 0 end as flag1
                
         from (
select Resource,PB,Quantity,convert(date,Start_Date) as Start_Date,convert(date,Finish_Date) as Finish_Date,
      LAG(convert(date, Finish_Date), 1,convert(date,Finish_Date)) OVER(
       ORDER BY Resource,convert(date, Start_Date) ASC) AS [Previous_FinshDate] from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Resource,convert(date, Start_Date)) row_num,* 
from temp1
) g
) k
) g
```

And check final result.

```
-- After sum and group by

select Resource AS Equipment, PB,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity,  MIN(Start_Date) as Start_Date,MAX(Finish_Date) as Finish_Date,flag from (
select *,

case when (convert(date,Start_Date) <=convert(date,Previous_FinshDate) 
        or convert(date,Start_Date) = dateadd(dd,1, convert(date,Previous_FinshDate))) then 1 else 0 end as flag,
case when convert(date,Start_Date) > dateadd(dd,1, convert(date,Previous_FinshDate)) then 1 else 0 end as flag1
                
         from (
select Resource,PB,Quantity,convert(date,Start_Date) as Start_Date,convert(date,Finish_Date) as Finish_Date,
      LAG(convert(date, Finish_Date), 1,convert(date,Finish_Date)) OVER(
       ORDER BY Resource,convert(date, Start_Date) ASC) AS [Previous_FinshDate] from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Resource,convert(date, Start_Date)) row_num,* 
from temp1
) g
) k
) g
group by g.Resource,g.PB,g.flag
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. When I run this code against the above dataset i get the below result   


  `Equipment PB Quantity         Start_Date Finish_Date flag
Equip#1     pb12 1106248.88 2021-01-02 2021-01-25 1
Equip#2     pb12 769.56         2021-01-25 2021-01-25 0
Equip#2     pb12 797833.67 2021-01-02 2021-01-25 1  `


The dates here aren't correct. row 3 and 4 cannot be distinct as the Finish_Date of row3 is the start of row 2. The expected result is as included in my initial request.